# initialize a radio button in redux-form 6.8.0

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

poor english
i wanna make option A initial selection;

i try this

```js
const child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      A:<input {...props.input} type="radio" value="A" />
      B:<input {...props.input} type="radio" value="B" />
    </div>)
}

let Index = () => (
  <form>
    <Field name="aaa" component={child} />
  </form>
)

Index = reduxForm({
  form: 'slb',
  initialValues: {
    aaa: 'A',
  }
})(Index);
```

but this does not work

please help me   thank you!

Comment: no use checked based value

Comment: can you do `console.log('props.input', props.input)` inside Child component and tell the output?

Comment: {name: 'aaa', value: 'A'}

Comment: try this: `<input {...props.input} checked={props.input.value} type="radio" value="A" />`